# FlatList is locking clicks when loading or refreshing data

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I'm using **FlatList** component to handle massive amount of data with pagination (requesting 15 by 15 for tests).

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.noMatches? this.state.monitorados : this.state.filtrados}
    keyExtractor={item => item.identificador}               
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
    style={styles.list}
    onEndReached={() => this.handleScroll()}
    onEndThreshold={0.5}
    renderItem={({item}) =>  (<SimpleItem item={item} />)} 
/>
```

I have a expand/collapse animation and nested components in each row. I'm using a custom component to handle the animation, some data-pickers, views, texts and other common.

When first 15 rows are rendered, I try to click to expand, but it do not responds immediately. Some seconds later I can click and the item expand, but its lagging a lot. More seconds, I can expand/collapse very well, every item of list react instantly.

If I slide down, 15 more items are requested and all that happens again: the clicks got locked, the first click lag so much, the next is highly performing.

**Gif demo:**

[image]

**Question:**

1. Can I somehow unlock clicks to expand/collapse even if component still loading?
2. Is there some way to optimize flatlist performance?

**Already tried:**

1. Moved nested components to other file and make it a Pure Component.
2. Removed styles.
3. Removed expand/collapse and test clicks in TouchableOpacity - same issue.

Comment: give unique key to each SimpleItem and use the key props to toggle your data

Comment: You can also try using this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand, should I create a prop like: `<SimpleItem key={item.identificador} />` and fecth data in there? VirtualizedList seems useful, I'm going to implement and will post result after

Comment: I might be late to the party, but did you ever find a solution to this @RajendranNadar?

Comment: @Gigalink try https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration